# Proof that intervals of the form $[x, x+1)$ or $(x, x+1]$ must contain a integer.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that any real interval of the form $[x, x+1)$ or $(x, x+1]$ must contain a integer.

Here is my proof (by contradiction)

We start by saying, assume the interval of the form $[x, x+1)$ or $(x, x+1]$ does not contain a integer. Now suppose $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, then x is in the interval $[x, x+1)$ and since $x$ is an integer, then $x+1$ must also be an integer.  Thus $(x, x+1]$ must also contain a integer. This is a contradiction, it contradicts our assumption.  Therefore the statement is true.

Can someone help me on this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two statements are equivalent:

- $[x, x+1)$ or $(x, x+1]$ always contains an integer
- $[x, x+1]$ always contains an integer.

For the proving, we can suppose, that $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$(otherwise $x$ is a trivial solution). Then, we can find an $y$, such that, $y > x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take the following set: {$y \in \mathbb{Z}, y > x$}. Since this set is bounded from below(and obviously not empty), it must have a minimal element, let this element be $m$.

We prove, that $m \in [x,x+1]$.

Since $x \notin \mathbb{Z},  |m-x| < 1$. Therefore, $m \in [x,x+1], m \in \mathbb{Z}$. **QED.**

Comment: Question is $m \in [ x, x + 1 )$, not $ m \in [x, x + 1 ]$.

Note that $2 \in [ 2, 3 ]$ but $3 \in [ 2, 3 ]$, while $2 \ne ( 2, 3 ]$ and $3 \ne [ 2, 3 )$.

In this context $[ x, x + 1 )$ or $ ( x, x + 1 ]$ is not the same as $[ x, x + 1 ) \cup ( x, x + 1 ]$

But still an upvote!!! :)

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, the question is trivial, so we don't need to discuss that, in other cases, that won't happen. But you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you've observed, if $x$ is an integer, then so is $x+1$, so in that case we are done. Otherwise let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $n>x$, which must exist because there are integers greater than $x$ and the interval $(x,\infty)\cap\mathbb Z$ is well ordered. I claim that $n<x+1$. If this were not true then we'd have $n-1>x$, contradicting the choice of $n$. Thus $n\in (x,x+1)$ and we are done.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your post before giving my answer; mine seems a bit like a re-wording of your answer.

Comment: @Gary it doesn't seem that way to me. In any case, no harm done.

Comment: @Abhi no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ 0 \le \{ x \} < 1,$$

where $\{ x \}$ is the fraction of $x$, thus $\{ x \} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor of $x$.

---

Thus

$$0 \le x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1,$$

or

$$x \ge \lfloor x \rfloor > x - 1.$$

Therefore

$$\lfloor x \rfloor \in ( x - 1, x ],$$

but also

$$\lfloor x+1 \rfloor \in ( x, x + 1 ],$$

and $\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$ is an integer.

---

But we also have

$$0 \le - x - \lfloor - x \rfloor < 1,$$

or

$$x \le - \lfloor - x \rfloor < x + 1.$$

Therefore

$$- \lfloor - x \rfloor \in [ x , x + 1 ),$$

and $- \lfloor - x \rfloor$ is an integer.

---

So there is always an integer element of either $ [ x, x + 1 ) $ or $ ( x, x + 1 ]$.

Comment: The part that you assume (before the horizontal line) requires proof. If you try prove it you'll notice that it's essentially what you are trying to prove in the first place.

Comment: Reformulation of @MattSamuel's comment: How would you even define the fractional-part function if you didn't already know what the OP is trying to prove?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $[x,x+1)$ does not contain an integer. Then $x$ is not an integer and neither is $x+1$. Then $[x,x+1]$ does not contain an integer. Assume WOLG, that $x=0.a_1a_2...$ , i.e., $x>0$. Then we must have $x+1 <1 $ (otherwise there would be an integer in the interval). But $x>0$ , so $x+1>1$, so there must be an integer in the interval. Similar argument for $(x,x+1]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved the statement only for $x\in\Bbb Z$.

If $x\notin\Bbb Z$, consider the set $A=\{t\in\Bbb Z: t>x\}$. This set is bounded below and not empty, and it is well-ordered. Let $n=\min A$. Try to prove that $n$ is in the interval.

Perhaps you should also visit [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348086/prove-that-arba-b-in-z-where-r-is-an-irrational-number-is-dense-in-r/1348094#1348094).